# Why does correlation changes so much when converting data to pseudo observations for copula fitting?

Tags: correlation, simulation, copula

I'm trying to model the joint distribution of time to failure of 2 (in future possibily more than 2) components. So far what I know is the following:

1. The marginals of these components are exponentially (sometimes weibull) distributed.
2. Ideally I'd like to be able to represent both positive and negative correlation.

I've tried to simulate data in the following way

```
set.seed(202)

# Generate correlation matrix
n <- 2
Sigma <- matrix(runif(n^2, min=-1, max=1), ncol=n)
Sigma <- (Sigma * lower.tri(Sigma)) + t(Sigma * lower.tri(Sigma))
diag(Sigma) <- 1
Sigma
dat <- MASS::mvrnorm(50000, mu=rep(0, n), Sigma=Sigma)
cor(dat)
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 1.0000000 0.3415866
#[2,] 0.3415866 1.0000000

# Convert to uniform in 0-1 U[0, 1] via integral transform
dat <- pnorm(dat)
#PerformanceAnalytics::chart.Correlation(dat)
cor(dat)
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 1.0000000 0.3270474
#[2,] 0.3270474 1.0000000

# Now convert to the desired marginals
LAMBDA_1 <- 0.001
LAMBDA_2 <- 0.0021
# Now convert to the desired marginals
dat[,1] <- qexp(dat[,1], rate=LAMBDA_1)
dat[,2] <- qexp(dat[,2], rate=LAMBDA_2)
#
cor(dat)
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 1.0000000 0.2983289
#[2,] 0.2983289 1.0000000
```

I have a few questions, but the number 1 is the main one:

1. I don't understand why the correlation changes so much when performing these operations. I thought it remained more or less around the initial value but in practice it always goes done, especially as you increase the number of marginals (for instance from 2 to 4). Why does this occur?
2. Using this technique I'm basically using a Gaussian copula to generate my desired correlated marginals. I don't think this is the appropriate way of simulating data. How can I choose a copula based on the dependence structure I want to simulate? E.g. if I want to simulate strong tail dependence what copula should I choose?
3. Typically what copulas are used for survival analysis?

Comment: I really do not get your first question. For the second and third question, try to use VineCopula package. For example, for tail dependence, try to use Clayton copula (lower tail) or Gumbel and Joe copula for the upper tails. Also, there is a survival version for many of the copulas.

Comment: For correlation measures that survive monotonic transformation without substantial change, use nonparametric correlations (Kendall or Spearman correlation); this is one reason (among several others) why they're a focus in copula work.